# whitelist domain names on Azure AD with App Registration

Tags: azure-active-directory, office365

The authentication process for O365 requires adding the redirect URL in a whitelist on the app’s dashboard on Azure.

However, this whitelist doesn't work with domain names. It requires to add the entire URL for every page which is not possible if you have a huge number of URLs, plus some of the URLs are dynamically generated by the backend.
Is it possible to whitelist the domain with all its sub-directories/URLs in one go?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not (unless you want to use wildcards, which you shouldn't).

In general when you need dynamic redirects,
you should store the location you want to redirect to locally in a cookie/session/local storage/session storage.
Then use a single redirect URL, and when you get the redirect there, get that stored "local redirect URL" from where you stored it, and redirect the user there.

I touched upon this on a recent article: https://joonasw.net/view/avoiding-wildcard-reply-urls-with-msal-js

Comment: Requirements :
a. User can open any page of the intranet without login (no login page). 
b. User can start his journey from any page on the intranet (can't predict user’s entry point)

The issue:
a. When calling the loginPopup it requires a redirect URI which will be used to redirect the user back to the page he was browsing once the login is done. 
b. The default redirect URI is the same as the URI that triggered the loginPopup call 
c. The problem is that this URI needs to be added in Redirect URIs list in the Azure dashboard under the Authentication tab

Comment: Change the default redirect URI to one that is used every time. Redirect from there to where they wanted to go originally.