# Azure AD Redirect URI(s) for applications that a multi tennant

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api, owin-middleware

I am responsible for a web application that we sell to customers all around the world, this application is a web application that I have been tasked with including functionality to surface O365 content within, this has lead me to the MS Graph API which I am currently implementing as a proof of concept.

At the moment I have everything working within my dev environment with localhost and dev URIs listed as application redirect URIs under the AD application, however, in the real world there could be an unlimited amount of URIs that our customers are using, meaning that as I currently understand it will mean that I am going to have to either: 
1) Get them to create an application within their own AD organisations or 
2) Manage the URIs within in our app here locally.

Now the question I have is, what is the best approach I can take here?
Is there a secret option 3 that I have not been able to dig out from the Microsoft documentation or the internet yet?

Thank you for any help or advice you can provide.

Comment: My answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/56341740/1658906 might help